# Making an Airline Reservation class and need help on how to make a Demo class to call the methods

Tags: java, methods, instantiation

So I have made this class that is booking seat for passengers and i have written all the methods

```
public class AirlineBooking
{
    String[]seatArray;
    public AirlineBooking()
    {
        seatArray = new String[10];
        for(int i =0;i<seatArray.length; i++)
        {
            seatArray[i] = "x";
        }
    }
    public void passengerList()
    {
        for(int i =0;i<seatArray.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Seat "+i+" -- "+ seatArray[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("---");
    }
    public void reserve(String name, int seat)
    {
        if(seatArray[seat].equals("x"))
        {
            seatArray[seat]= name;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Choose another seat");
        }
    }
    public void availableVacantSeats()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<seatArray.length; i++)
        {
            if(seatArray[i].equals("x"))
            {
                System.out.println("Seat " + (i+1)+ " = "+ seatArray[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    public void cancelReservation(String passengerName, int seat)
    {
        if(seatArray.equals(seatArray[seat]))
        {
            seatArray[seat]="x";
        }

    }
    public void coupleSeats()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        {
            if(seatArray[i].equals("X")&&seatArray[i+1].equals("X"))
            {
                System.out.println("Seat "+i+" and "+(i+1));

            }
        }
    }


}
```

This seems to work fine but I cannot remember how to create a Class that calls these methods. So far I have

```
public class AirlineDemo
{

    Airline new Airline= myAirline

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {


        myAirline.passengerList();

    }


}
```

but it is not working at all. Help would be very appreciated.

Comment: There is no method `printpassengerSeat()` in class `Airline`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AirlineDemo
{
public static void main(String[]args)
    {

        Airline myAirline= new Airline ();
        myAirline.printpassengerSeat(); //provided this method exists
        myAirline.passengerList();

    }

}
```

I would suggest you to start with some java beginners guide

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html
https://thenewcircle.com/bookshelf/java_fundamentals_tutorial/object_oriented.html

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_quick_guide.htm

Comment: You might like to mention that there is no such method called printpassengerSeat ;)

Comment: Yes I know that it was just part of when I was messing with it to try to get it to work. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You are making mistake during creating a object try like below.

```
 public class AirlineDemo
    {



        public static void main(String[]args)
        {
            AirlineBooking myAirline = new AirlineBooking();
            myAirline.printpassengerSeat();//this method should be in the Airline Class. In your class this method is not present.
            myAirline.passengerList();

        }

    }
```

Comment: I have done this
public class AirlineDemo
{

 Airline  myAirline= new Airline();

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {


     myAirline.passengerList();
     myAirline.availableVacantSeats();

    }


}
And it is saying these following errors
Cannot find symbol class Airline
Cannot find symbol class Airline
non-static variable myAirline cannot be referenced from static context

Comment: Sorry I did one mistake. Now I edited my answer.Now Try...@user2838611

Comment: I have tried to apply your change but it is still not calling the methods from my AirlineBooking Class.

Comment: Its saying cannot find symbol method availableVacantSeats() and cannot find symbol method passengerList()

Comment: That is when I rename Airline to AirlineDemo. When i leave Airline as Airline it says cannot find symbol class Airline

Comment: your class name is AirlineBooking which have all methods. so use AirlineBooking rather than Airline.See my updated answer.

Comment: AHHHH my god. I didn't have them in the same folder for some reason. Thank you for your help/

Answer (score 0):

I have done this

```
public class AirlineDemo
{

    Airline  myAirline= new Airline();

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {


        myAirline.passengerList();
        myAirline.availableVacantSeats();

    }


}
```

And it is saying these following errors Cannot find symbol class Airline Cannot find symbol class Airline non-static variable myAirline cannot be referenced from static context